Geckodriver para fireFox "133.0.3"
Estou fazendo automação utilizando Chrome.driver, agora quero executar o mesmo código com geckodriver.driver no Firefox. A versão do meu Firefox é "133.0.3 (64-bits)"
Entrei nesse link: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
E baixei as versões 0.35.0, 0.34.0, 0.33.0, 0.30.0, mas nenhum é compatível com meu firefox. Alguém sabe qual é a versão compatível para meu Firefox "133.0.3 (64-bits)" e a onde eu encontro?versao firefox
versao geckodriver
